# Checking entries in a database issue with a while loop

Tags: android, database, sqlite, cursor, rows

```
 Integer c=0;

 DatabaseHelper dbh1 = new DatabaseHelper(this);
 Cursor ca = dbh1.getReadableDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);

 while (ca.moveToNext()) 

 { 
     String Ans6 = ca.getString(ca.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.VALUE6));
     if ( Ans6.equals("Automatic"))
      {
       c+=1;
      }  
 }
 String strI = Integer.toString(c);

 Toast toast=Toast.makeText(this, strI, 2000);
 toast.show();
```

I have a SQlite database setup in android. The table has been successfully set up and I am trying to check values from column VALUE6 if it matches Automatic. The cursor has to go through every row and check the value of VALUE6  in that row and return how many rows have Automatic. Is my code right? any ideas? strI returns 0 every time i run the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a brute force way of doing it.  Why not query for that value and then get the count of the  rows in the returned cursor?

```
Cursor ca = dbh1.getReadableDatabase().query(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, DatabaseHelper.VALUE6 + "='AUTOMATIC'", null, null, null, null);
int count = ca.getCount();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Heed this wisdom.  Make the database do your work for you when you can.

Comment: THANKS Barak . This is what happens when you don't know how to Query.

Comment: Well, there's query and then there's Android query (imo).  I would recommend reading up on standard SQL query and then dive into the android specific bits on the dev site.  I have to run, but if someone else doesn't post some links I'll try to when I get back.